# Retrieve .cs file from bin/Debug folder in C#

Tags: c#

I am a newbie to C# and I am trying to retrieve the .cs file from the Debug folder of the application. This application is deployed in our another server with only Debug folder in it. But from there, I am not able to retrieve the .cs file associated with it.

I wonder is it something that is possible in C#. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: "bin" is short for Binaries...VS writes the compiled assembly there, it doesnt distribute your source code with it.

Comment: Why would there be a `.cs` file in the `bin` folder? It's compiled into the `.exe` or `.dll` usually.

Comment: While getting the .cs file may not be possible, you could use something like Redgate's .NET Reflector program to look at the DLL file to see the code.

Comment: The .cs file is source code. Debug and Bin folders will contain executables and other compiler stuff. So you're not going to find a .cs file in any of those folders. The .cs would be in the actual project directory under "src" usually. Please post details about your directory structure so we can see what you're dealing with.

Comment: This is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/); you have some problem X and you thought “I know, I'll retrieve the .cs file from the Debug folder! That'll get me X!” Now you discover that won't work. You need to tell us what X is. Are you trying to deploy an application to another server? You need to tell us what kind of application it is; ASP.NET? UWP? WPF? WinForms?

Answer (score 0):

The .cs files are not going to be accessible in the Debug folder, or any other release directory.

When you compile your program, the .cs files are all compiled into a DLL or EXE file.

.cs files are the raw code for your application & is only used by the code editor and the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible if you decompile the dll using something like [DotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/download/#section=web-installer)